# Dynamically update DataGrid rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` like this:

```
    class SearchFile
    {
        public string path { set; get; }
        public int count { set; get; }
    }

   //...

        files = new List<SearchFile>();

        DataGridTextColumn col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        DataGridTextColumn col2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        col1.Header = "File";
        col2.Header = "count";
        col1.Binding = new Binding("path");
        col2.Binding = new Binding("count");
        dataGrid1.Columns.Add(col1);
        dataGrid1.Columns.Add(col2);
```

I do this to populate the items source:

```
            foreach(var file in allFiles)
            {
                SearchFile sf = new SearchFile() { path=file, count=c };
                files.Add(sf);
            }
```

The above is a part of an event handler that will be launched multiple times. Where do I bind the `files` to the `ItemsSource` property so that it's dynamically updated? I tried putting it after the foreach loop, but only the first run has any effect and the grid doesn't change on subsequent runs (when `allFiles` is different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ObservableCollection`. It provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed:

```
files = new ObservableCollection<SearchFile>();
```